# How do I send selected value of dropdown list from one view to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set dropdown list value from one view to another. I am not getting it even though both view has the same model.

My First View is, from which I would like to send value

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicantDetails", "Applicant", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },     FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <section class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Applicant Detail</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Salutation, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-xs-2 salutation">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Salutation, Model.Salutation, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Salutation, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName,null,new {@class = "text-warning"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new {Id = "datepicker", @class = "form-control calender" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryofResidence, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CountryofResidence, new { Id = "countryofresidence", @class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryofResidence, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryofNationality, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CountryofNationality, new { Id = "countryofnationality", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryofNationality, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Currency, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-2"> 
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Currency, Model.Currency, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Currency, null, new { @class = "text-warning" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
</section>
    }
</div>
```

and my second view is in which I would like to display value and in the salutation TextBox I would like to get first view salutation selected value

```
<div class="row row-placing">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Compare", "Quote", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <section class="form-horizontal form-horizontal-placing">
            <div class="form-group table-formgroup">
                <table class="table table-striped table-layout" id="table-dynamic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="success">
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>SurName</th>
                            <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th class="table-heading-phone">Phone Number</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="row1">
                            <td>
                                <span>1</span> 
                                @Html.TextBox("Salutation", new { @Value = "");
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@Value = Model.FirstName,  @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new {@Value = Model.Surname, @class = "form-control " })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Surname)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, new {@Value = Model.DOB,  @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DOB)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@Value = Model.Email,  @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Extensions, Model.Extensions, "Ext", new { @class = "form-control ext0" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Extensions)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control phonenumber0" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row2"></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="depedent">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="col-md-2 ">
                            <label class="control-label">Enter Dependent</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" name="numberofdependent" class="form-control numberofdepedentextbox " />
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="button" name="AddChild" value="Add Dependents" class="btn btn-primary btn-click" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="button" name="SaveDependent" value="Save Dependents" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: plz post some code???\

Comment: Its not clear what you trying to do. Are your redirecting from the post method to the second view? You need to post you controller. And why are you doing `@Html.TextBox("Salutation", new { @Value = "");`

Answer (score 0):

This all handled in your post and get methods of your controller first post the view that will take in the model and than instead of posting the same view back or a successful view etc you can return it to the view you want passing the model in ... But I'm unsure exactly what you trying to do